# Svn2Rally Connector Extension

Tags: ruby, api, svn, rally, connector

I have used the [latest connector](https://help.rallydev.com/subversion-vcs-installation-user-guide) from Rally and set it up with Task Scheduler to run periodically. It works well, however I have encountered problems when trying to extend it.

Within the config.yml file used, there is an `UpdateArtifactState` flag that I believe, when set to True, will make use of the statex.rb file. This file handles how the commit message from SVN is parsed. It is here that I find my problem;

I want to extend the connector to allow for the # symbol to be included in the Rally task identifier (`DE55555 -> #DE5555` for example). However, upon testing this file does not seem to be used.

Question: if my assumption is correct, and the statex.rb file is merely an example and not used in execution, how can I extend the Rally Connector to pick up tags the way I see fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following:

make a new Ruby class and put it in to the extension subdirectory.

Example: extension/my_state_extractor.rb
            in this file he has a class defined as 'MyStateExtractor'

Pattern your file from the statex.rb file.
Then, in your config in the Rally section, you'll need an entry of

```
StateExtractorClass :         MyStateExtractor(message)
```

Customarily this entry will follow the entry for UpdateArtifactState : True